# Using a variable URL in a JSON-call, not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to make a simple weather app and it seems I can't access any information using my variable for the JSON-link. Heres my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var key = 'a91a892f1f2a1aa3f7409a78f72af675';
    var locationURL = 'http://ip-api.com/json';
    var longitude;
    var latitude;

    //Getting the geolocation from the user
    $.getJSON(locationURL, function(data) {
        longitude = data.lon;
        latitude = data.lat;
        var url = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude + '&appid=' + key;
        console.log(url);
        $.getJSON(url, function(data2){
            console.log(data2, url);
        });

    });
});
```

But I get no return from the second JSON-call, and it seems like the variable 'url' is broken or something. What am I doing wrong or not seeing here?

Comment: You should always check the Javascript console for errors before posting here. If you had, it might have helped you solve the problem yourself, or at least post a more complete question.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing protocol:

```
var url = '//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + latitude + '&lon=' + longitude + '&appid=' + key;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get: function(req, data, callback) {
    data.gym_hash = this.gym_hash;
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: rest.server + req,
        type: 'GET',
        data: data,

        success: function(result) {
            callback(result);
        }
    });
}
```

I use this type if code and let js and jQuery do the magic of formatting the parameters into the url. Call is like this:

```
       get(
        "Path/To/Rest",
        {
            email: email,
            password: password,

        },
        function(result){console.log(result);});
```